# What does this woman want to say?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, spoken-english, figurative-language, sentence

Would you kindly help me to understand what does the woman said here in these few seconds " 25:3 to 25:14" I really couldn't understand it

https://fb.watch/fh9a2egKL2/

Comment: Good question. I've no clue what she is saying.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's not a question about learning English. Questions on this site must be about learning specific aspects of English. Requesting scripts for random audio samples doesn't fit into that.

Comment: So, um, I think that... I think that it's powerful to find things that you like: Angela saying her favorite show, just chilling on the sofa; Tasha saying reading for a... for a bit, enhancement of her information for... for self-act... for her own self-actualization and growth.  Um, spending time, sometimes, just spending time alone.